# How to extract duplicate rows and merge them by certain variable

Tags: r, duplicates

the title is a bit confusing but I have a dataset that looks like this: `head(df)`

```
ID  Race                               Disease
1 8818894 White                 Hepatitis C - chronic
2 8818894 White                 Hepatitis C - chronic
3 8421024 White                    Campylobacteriosis
4 8420854 White                          Tuberculosis
5 8266841 White                     Cryptosporidiosis
6 8241742 White Hepatitis B (including delta) - acute
```

Some id's are duplicated because, they are both white AND hispanic so it created an observation for both of their "races".

I would like to merge these IDs and have their race read "white, hispanic". Is there an easy way to do this? I assume it would be a bit complicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite straightforward: group by ID, paste and collapse unique values from the other columns..

**custom sample data with duplicate ID Whites/Hispanic**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread('ID  Race                               Disease
 8818894 White                 "Hepatitis C - chronic"
 8818894 Hispanic                 "Hepatitis C - chronic"
 8421024 White                   "Campylobacteriosis"
 8420854 White                          "Tuberculosis"
 8266841 White                     "Cryptosporidiosis"
 8241742 White "Hepatitis B (including delta) - acute"')

# data.table::fread() reads the text directly to a data.tale format. If you 
# already have your data in a data.frame, you can convert it using 
# data.table::setDT(mydata)
```

**code**

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = " & ")), by = .(ID)]

#         ID             Race                               Disease
# 1: 8818894 White & Hispanic                 Hepatitis C - chronic
# 2: 8421024            White                    Campylobacteriosis
# 3: 8420854            White                          Tuberculosis
# 4: 8266841            White                     Cryptosporidiosis
# 5: 8241742            White Hepatitis B (including delta) - acute
```

**code explanation**

`DT`: your data in a data.table format (see sample code above)
`lapply(...)`: loops over the first element, which is
`.SD`: all the columns in your data (that are not included in the
grouping `by`-argument at the end.
If you only want to select a couple of columns to loop over, you can use the `.SDcols`-selector. More on this in the helpfile from data.table.

So, we group DT `by` ID. The we loop (`lapply`) over each column (`.SD`), call this column variable `x` (`function(x)`) and perform the following function:
`paste0(unique(x), collapse = " & "))`; this gets all unique (`unique`) elements from the current column, and pastes (`paste0`) them together (`collapse`) using a given separator (`" & "`).

Comment: Hi thank you for this! I am trying to figure out the syntax here but am a bit confused:

What I have is 

`mydataframe[, lapply(.SD, function(Race) paste0(unique(Race), collapse = " & ")), by = .(ID)]`

Apologies for the trouble!

Comment: I added som explanation in my answer above.